# How can commits with same hash have different history?

Tags: git

I have a git repo, let's call it `sub`. I tagged the commit `75accac4` with v7.1.2023.227:
History of main branch with changes from PR 79

```
$ git log v7.1.2023.227 --pretty=format:"%h %ad %d"
75accac Tue Aug 15 07:31:15 2023 +0000  (HEAD, tag: v7.1.2023.227)
0406c95 Thu May 25 10:57:32 2023 +0200
e535e85 Mon Aug 14 07:57:40 2023 +0000
[...]
```

I then referenced that tag from another repo `super` which has `sub` as a submodule.
Just to find out that the changes that were made in PR 79 were missing.
Checked what happended in the middle commit `0406c956`, the changes were not removed there.

So I investigated a little futher and found that when showing the history for the tag, the commits from PR 79 were missing completely:
History of tag with changes from PR 79 missing

```
$ git log origin/main --pretty=format:"%h %ad %d"
6c9a0d3 Tue Aug 15 07:38:29 2023 +0000  (origin/main)
75accac Tue Aug 15 07:31:15 2023 +0000  (tag: v7.1.2023.227)
0406c95 Thu May 25 10:57:32 2023 +0200
08f73ff Mon Aug 14 08:37:18 2023 +0000
14232e7 Mon Aug 14 08:35:17 2023 +0000
ce979ae Mon Aug 14 08:34:23 2023 +0000
04bd5ff Mon Aug 14 08:29:52 2023 +0000
e535e85 Mon Aug 14 07:57:40 2023 +0000
[...]
```

How is this possible?
How can two git-histories that originate from the same commit (`e535e85`) and diverge afterwards finally have the same `head` commit hash (`75accac`)?

I'm starting to doubt my understanding of git and hash trees.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. The commit 08f73ffb with text "Merged PR 79" is not part of the history that ends in 75accac4.

Comment: It sounds like a **display** problem. Some commits might be voluntarily omitted from this specific display, while still being in history, akin to what you get with `git log --all --decorate --simplify-by-decoration`

Comment: Your screenshots are completely pixelated to me, please post in higher resolution & quality, or even better post as text: `git log --oneline --graph` as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first graph you posted, you will note that "Merge PR 79" appears to be a merge in the "wrong direction": the edge in the graph goes from left to right.

This display may mislead you into thinking that this particular merge is part of your tagged version, but it actually isn't.

These changes appear to be merged into `main` afterwards, with PR 85.

Comment: Ok, I think I nearly grasped it now. It seemed to be just the display that mislead me. I updated the answer with text output from `git log ... --pretty=format:"%h %ad %d"`. 
Does this command simply omit the characters showing graph information? Meaning the intermediate commits 04bd5ff  to 08f73ff are not really on my branch? But they then got integrated with the merging commit 6c9a0d3?

Comment: @Danno: add the `--graph` option, and git will draw (in ascii art) the graph -- this option is not on by default. `%s` (lowercase `s`) will also show the short message for the commit -- you will note that it is much easier to edit out text before posting than an image ... ;)